# rasterize in qgis based on foreign table data

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have  a few tables imported into `QGIS` as vector layer. These tables are linked to a vector `SHP` file with `foreign key`as 1:M relation.

So, the data structure is as follows:

```
shp file linked to table1
shp file linked to table2
table2   linked to table3
```

Now when I click on a feature in shp file and open form, the data from table1, table2 and table3 all are displayed.

How do I rasterize the vector shp file based on data existing in table3 only (only one column of table3) ?

Comment: I think you would need to save your vector layer as a new shapefile with the joined tables and then rasterize this instead.

Comment: @Joseph saving as a new layer would work for table joins only. In this case I've used relations manager to specify 1:M relation. I need to use these data from the foreign tables that are not joined but related.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Your question makes no mention of a 1:many relate being involved.